# Store pwd in file that can be used to return to that path on launch

Tags: bash, shell

I have created a file in my home directory called .curdir.txt, and written a function in my .bashrc that fills that file with the pwd every time I issue a cd command. So the file always contains the last directory I CDed into. That part is working.

I would like to use this file to return to whatever directory it contains when I duplicate my session. So far I haven't had any luck figuring it out.

Here is the working part (I added into my function that shows my pwd at all times):

```
function __cd
{
  cd $1;
  PS1="`uname -n`::`pwd`> ";
  CURDIR=`pwd`
  echo ${CURDIR} > ~/.curdir.txt
}

alias cd=__cd
```

Every time I change my directory the new path is stored in the text file just fine. I have tried a number of methods to reference that file and return to that path when I start a duplicated session. I figured if I can get it to echo I'd be almost done, but I can't even get that. Currently it looks like this:

```
echo $(~/.curdir.txt)
cd $(~/.curdir.txt)
```

I have tried this. I've pushing the contents of the file into a variable and using that. I just can't get it. Any advice?

I should probably add my output with the current setup.

```
SIMONEY@rhvmap01s password:
Send automatic password
Last login: Wed Apr 13 09:08:53 2016 from SIMONEY.int.myco.org
Kickstarted on 2014-10-08
/home/SIMONEY/.curdir.txt: line 1: /home/SIMONEY: is a directory

/home/SIMONEY/.curdir.txt: line 1: /home/SIMONEY: is a directory
```

Like I said, I'm putting all this into my .bashrc, and the txt file is located in my home directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cd $(cat ~/.curdir.txt)`. You need `cat` to read the contents. Just `$(~/.curdir.txt)` will try to execute the file, if it is executable, otherwise doesn't do anything.

Other than this you might want to look at the `pushd` and `popd` directory stacks and how to use them. They are very useful for jumping around the system.

Comment: I've looked into pushd and popd a little bit. It looks like they won't work from session to session, but I might be wrong. I haven't looked too much into them. I did realize I should try cat right after I wrote this.

On a funny note, you're right. It attempts to execute, and I think it might turn my file into an executable. This would explain why my file keeps turning into an executable!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the contents of the file to a variable

```
var="$(cat file)"
```

but for your need check `pushd` `popd` which does what you need. Also `cd -` returns to previous directory.